# iOS - Allow default row movement in `UITableView` without editing mode

Tags: ios, uitableview, default

I want to allow the default row movement in a `UITableView` without it being in editing mode, and without compromising the default behaviour of the `UITableView`.

[image: movable cell]

The image above displays a cell in editing mode, with movement enabled.

I tried simply running `for (UIView *subview in cell.subviews)` (while my `UITableView` was in editing mode), but the button didn't turn up:

```
<UITableViewCellScrollView: 0x8cabd80; frame = (0 0; 320 44); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8c9ba20>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8ca14b0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
```

How can allow/add the movement "button" without enabling editing mode in my `UITableView`?

Creating and adding a `UIButton` with the default `function` for movement is also an option.

Comment: Maybe try the method in this recent article:http://www.raywenderlich.com/63089/cookbook-moving-table-view-cells-with-a-long-press-gesture

Comment: That could work, and I know this method to be possible. But my question is how to do enable it with the default code for cell movement.

Comment: @AleksanderAzizi May I ask why you fear the editing mode?

Comment: But why not present the table view in editing mode in the first place? I will tell you why I suggest this. Without touching private API, it is not possible to use Apple's reorder methods. You will have to implement yourself or use an open source (there are available).

Comment: Answered using 100% tableview delegate methods. I use this code on a live app.

Comment: @LeoNatan I thought that could work as well, but the default swipe (left) to delete is then disabled.

Answer (score 30):

I actually do something similar for one of my apps. It uses the delegate methods for table editing and a bit of 'tricking' the user. **100% built-in Apple functionality.**

1 - **Set the table to editing (I do it in viewWillAppear)**

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView setEditing:YES];
}
```

2 - **Hide the default accessory icon:**

```
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
        editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        //remove any editing accessories (AKA) delete button 
        return UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
       }
```

3 - **Keep editing mode from moving everything to the right (in the cell)**

```
 -(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
return NO;
}
```

4 - At this point you should be able to drag the cells around without it looking like it is in editing mode. Here we trick the user. Create your own "move" icon (three lines in the default case, whatever icon you want in your case) and add the imageView right where it would normally go on the cell.

5 - **Finally, implement the delegate method to actually rearrange your underlying datasource.**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath{

    //Get original id
    NSMutableArray *originalArray = [self.model.items objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.section];
    Item * original = [originalArray objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];

    //Get destination id
    NSMutableArray *destinationArray = [self.model.items objectAtIndex:destinationIndexPath.section];
    Item * destination = [destinationArray objectAtIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];

    CGPoint temp = CGPointMake([original.section intValue], [original.row intValue]);

    original.row = destination.row;
    original.section = destination.section;

    destination.section = @(temp.x);
    destination.row = @(temp.y);

    //Put destination value in original array
    [originalArray replaceObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row withObject:destination];

    //put original value in destination array
    [destinationArray replaceObjectAtIndex:destinationIndexPath.row withObject:original];

    //reload tableview smoothly to reflect changes
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [UIView transitionWithView:tableView duration:duration options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
            [tableView reloadData];
        } completion:NULL];
    });
 }
```

Comment: I thought this could work as well, I have the exact same code, but the default swipe (left) to delete is disabled when the `UITableView` is in editing mode. Ergo my question on how to enable the row movement without using editing mode.

Comment: If you need swipe left then enable it using a different implementation.  Look at my app that uses this, under the grocery list. This sounds like exactly what you are looking for. http://appstore.com/mealidea

Comment: My swipe implementation here is basic, but if you embed a scrollview in the cell, you can get the same effect apple has

Comment: You can't edit a table without putting it in edit mode! Short of gesture recognizers, screenshots and manually moving each cell this is as close as it gets

Comment: Also, your question only asks about default row movement. It has NO mention of swipe to delete...

Comment: Very well, I added a section to my question which should be obvious. The answer you have given uses the exact same code I already have, and it causes the problem of compromising other functionality in the `UITableView`, rendering it useless in this case.

Comment: The bounty will expire in less than 24 hours. If you wish to have the full bounty amount (300), please modify your answer so it for fills `without compromising the default behaviour of the UITableView`. If the criteria is not met, only half (150) will be given to you, and your answer will not be accepted.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "without compromising the dedault behavior of the UITableView" I think this code already does that...

Comment: `compromising the default behaviour` in this case refers to how the `UITableView` works and behaves when used normally. By appending your code to an existing fully working `UITableView`, functions like (including but not limited to) "swipe to delete/remove" is compromised (not operational).

Comment: @AleksanderAzizi - curious why you didn't like my solution which doesn't "compromise the default behavior" of the tableview.

Answer (score 7):

William Falcon's answer in **swift 3**

1 - **Set the table to editing (I do it in viewWillAppear)**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewWillAppear(animated: animated)
   tableView.setEditing(true, animated: false)
}
```

2 - **Hide the default accessory icon:**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return .none
}
```

3 - **Keep editing mode from moving everything to the right (in the cell)**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

4 - Not required in swift 3

5 - Reorder your array

**Extra Note**

If you want to have your table cells selectable, add the following code within `viewWillAppear()` function.

```
tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = true
```

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 5... I know the question asks WITHOUT editing, but if your only functionality needs are to

1. be able to reorder cells and
2. be able to select cells

Then you can follow this (source for reorder: https://www.ralfebert.de/ios-examples/uikit/uitableviewcontroller/reorderable-cells/):

1. set `tableView.isEditing = true`
2. set `tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = true`
3. With `UITableViewDataSource`, add the following methods:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
    return .none
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

You may or may not need to override those functions. I didn't need to.

4. (I think) in UITableViewDelegate, add this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    let movedObject = items[sourceIndexPath.row]
    items.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    items.insert(movedObject, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
}
```

where items is the data source array that handles the number of items in your table view.

The key is step 2, in which you can finally add the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to set the `UITableView` into editing mode then you will need to reinvent the capability for dragging cells around.

I present a fairly complete solution that enables the user to move rows around within the visible area of the `UITableView`.  It works whether the `UITableView` is in editing mode or not.  You'll need to extend it if you want the table to scroll when a row is dragged near the top or bottom of the visible area.   There are likely some failure and edge cases you'll need to ferret out as well.

```
@implementation TSTableViewController
{
    NSMutableArray* _dataSource;
}

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _dataSource = [NSMutableArray new];
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ )
    {
        [_dataSource addObject: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"cell %d", i]];
    }
}

- (void) longPress: (UILongPressGestureRecognizer*) lpgr
{
    static NSString* dragCellData = nil;
    static UIView*   dragCellView = nil;
    static NSInteger dragCellOffset = 0;

    // determine the cell we're hovering over, etc:
    CGPoint pt = [lpgr locationInView: self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath* ip = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: pt];
    UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: ip];
    CGPoint ptInCell = [lpgr locationInView: cell];

    // where the current placeholder cell is, if any:
    NSInteger placeholderIndex = [_dataSource indexOfObject: @"placeholder"];

    switch ( lpgr.state )
    {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
        {
            // get a snapshot-view of the cell we're going to drag:
            cell.selected = cell.highlighted = NO;
            dragCellView = [cell snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates: YES];
            dragCellView.clipsToBounds       = NO;
            dragCellView.layer.shadowRadius  = 10;
            dragCellView.layer.shadowColor   = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
            dragCellView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
            dragCellView.frame = [cell convertRect: cell.bounds
                                        toView: self.tableView.window];

            // used to position the dragCellView nicely:
            dragCellOffset = ptInCell.y;

            // the cell will be removed from the view hierarchy by the tableview, so transfer the gesture recognizer to our drag view, and add it into the view hierarchy:
            [dragCellView addGestureRecognizer: lpgr];
            [self.tableView.window addSubview: dragCellView];


            // swap out the cell for a placeholder:
            dragCellData = _dataSource[ip.row];
            _dataSource[ip.row] = @"placeholder";

            [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: @[ip]
                                  withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

            break;
        }

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
        {
            // where should we move the placeholder to?
            NSInteger insertIndex = ptInCell.y < cell.bounds.size.height / 2.0 ? ip.row : ip.row + 1;
            if ( insertIndex != placeholderIndex )
            {
                // remove from the datasource and the tableview:
                [_dataSource removeObjectAtIndex: placeholderIndex];
                [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: @[ [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: placeholderIndex inSection: 0] ]
                                      withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                // adjust:
                if ( placeholderIndex < insertIndex )
                {
                    insertIndex--;
                }

                // insert to the datasource and tableview:
                [_dataSource insertObject: @"placeholder"
                                  atIndex: insertIndex];
                [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths: @[ [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: insertIndex inSection: 0] ]
                                      withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            }

            // move our dragCellView
            CGRect f = dragCellView.frame;
            f.origin.y = pt.y - dragCellOffset;
            dragCellView.frame = f;

            break;
        }

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
        {
            // replace the placeholdercell with the cell we were dragging
            [_dataSource replaceObjectAtIndex: placeholderIndex
                                   withObject: dragCellData];
            [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: @[ [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: placeholderIndex inSection: 0] ]
                                  withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

            // reset state
            [dragCellView removeFromSuperview];
            dragCellView = nil;
            dragCellData = nil;

            break;
        }

        default:
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _dataSource.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString* cellData = _dataSource[indexPath.row];
    if ( [cellData isEqualToString: @"placeholder" ] )
    {
        // an empty cell to denote where the "drop" would go
        return [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier: nil];
    }

    // a cell...
    UITableViewCell* cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                                   reuseIdentifier: nil];

    // our "fake" move handle & gesture recognizer

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer* lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector( longPress:) ];
    lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 0.3;

    UILabel* dragLabelView = [UILabel new];
    dragLabelView.text = @"☰";
    dragLabelView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [dragLabelView addGestureRecognizer: lpgr];
    [dragLabelView sizeToFit];

    cell.textLabel.text = cellData;

    if ( tableView.isEditing )
    {
        cell.editingAccessoryView = dragLabelView;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryView = dragLabelView;
    }

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the cells move you have to implement the corresponding `<UITableViewDelegate>` methods for moving and explicit allowing the cell (indexpath) to move. The move-indicator icon will not show up because it depends on editing mode. While the tableview is in editing state the move-icon will overlap the accessoryType icon. Edit mode comes by default with the round delete button on the left side which you can hide like so while editing.

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (self.editing) return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```

This way you keep your UITableView class with UITableViewDelegate methods clean to understand, you don't need to implement some kind of self-made move-mode.
And you can use the tableview's editing property to distinguish how the cell should look like in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. So even turning off the move-functionality is easier by setting your tableview back to `editing = NO`, the move-icon would disappear and the accessoryType symbol shows up again.