# iOS - Enable the default "swipe to delete" function in a UITableView while editing mode is enabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, default

It should be noted that this question comes from not being able to swipe to delete when enabling editing mode: [iOS - Allow default row movement in `UITableView` without editing mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22849825/ios-allow-default-row-movement-in-uitableview-without-editing-mode).

I want to enable the default (swiping) function for showing the delete button, while the `UITableView` is in editing mode.

[image: Image of cell with delete button visible]

I am aware of the ability to show the delete button constantly (to the left) while in editing mode, this is **not** what I want.

Comment: There isn't a way to do this, as far as I can see. Not without creating custom cells.